# In a QML application, using the Model/View framework, how can I change the data in the C++ data models from another C++ QOBJECT class in my project?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The examples from Qt and other forums explain how to connect your C++ data models with your QML delegates, but how can you access these C++ data models from another QObject inherited class in C++?

In applications where data is read over the network (tcp/udp, database or http), how can you set the data in your C++ data model with data from a C++ tcp/udp client?

I have seen examples of this using javascript in QML (REST and SQL) or by using C++ SQL models, but nothing showing how this can be done from custom classes, such as a tcp client implementation.

Using a tcp client as an example, what would be the best approach for populating a C++ data model (e.g a qabstractlistmodel implementation) with data read from a tcp socket?

Should for instance the tcp client be instantiated inside the model itself?
Or should the model be passed as a reference to the tcp client?

What is the "correct" way of going about this?

Comment: Either option is valid

Comment: @eyllanesc is correct either way is valid as long as your code is efficient. My preference would be that the model is passed as a ref, that way the model isn't trying to contain more memory in the form of the tcpclient and you can mess with the data after disposal of tcpclient.

Comment: Speaking in MVC terms the TCP class is a data provider and should not be disposed suddenly or if yes it should inform the model about that. The same in SOLID, especially S, the model class have to know nothing about data provider realization.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have passed as reference for now, which works so far in my application.